# Courseware project using WPF

Tags: wpf

I would like to see some eCourseware for online learning. I starting to learn WPF. I wish to develop a Courseware project using WPF eventually. Can anyone provide me some WPF projects through Courseware development? These can either be applications written entirely for showcasing WPF features, or real-world applications written in WPF. Obviously the source code would need to be available.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has quite a few samples on WPF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771633.aspx)

This [PowerPoint-like app](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=49) by Bea Stollnitz would also be a great addition to showing what WPF can do.